# Isaiah 40:4 -- is the word pronounced "geh" or "gay"?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, pronunciation, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book, haftarah

כָּל גֶּיא יִנָּשֵׂא

(In [Isaiah 40:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.40.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), and therefore also the Haftarah for *Nachamu*, just after *Tisha B'Av.*)

It's a *segol* under the gimmel so I'd say "geh" ... but then there's a yud, but it's not vowelized. Is the yud truly silent, and therefore *geh*; or is it pronounced with the yud, and therefore "gay"?

(Yes I realize this has absolutely nothing to do with the word "gay" in English ...)

Comment: According to the "[Chabad Baal Koreh](https://www.chabad.org/library/howto/trainer_cdo/aid/1771208/jewish/Learn-to-Read-Torah-and-Haftarah-With-Trope-Audio.htm#0=32494&1=1355&2=32862&3=24858&4=v125)" it is pronounced "gey".

Comment: @Dani that's mistaken (or perhaps based on a different chassidic dialect of Hebrew vowels than the OP speaks; I haven't listened). It's just a plain segol with no pronounced yud, like in word עיניך from shema.

Comment: Drives me *nuts* when people pronounce the second yud in words like that. ("One man's *i hachi* is another's *in hachi nami*, which is our *daas shotim*.)

Comment: There's a video of a Teimani chacham going through the options ... but it assumes a Teimani system of pronunciation and thus leaves me befuddled.

Comment: @Shalom it's interesting you say that because this was actually a big debate in Yemen, some hundreds of years ago

Comment: The yod is mute. There is no way to pronunce gey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I'm loathe to get involved with transliterations here, "geh" looks much closer to accurate to me than "gay".

The general rule in Tanakh is a letter is only pronounced if it has a vowel mark. The exception to that rule is if it is a sheva nach on the last letter of the word, where it is usually omitted as obvious.

In your case we have a use of a י as a mater lectionis to represent the segol vowel, like in other words עיניך אליך לפניך עליה תראינה. The י is not pronounced in any way. If it were pronounced, like in the word לילה, there would be a sheva mark under the י.

This is the only place in Tanakh where the segol vowel is written plene not as part of a suffix, so it does throw people off and many don't notice the difference with the more common conjugation גַּיְא or גֵּיא. (There are some variant manuscripts that do include a sheva under the י here, but they are a minority. The Aleppo Codex and related manuscripts do not include a sheva there.)

See [this article](https://nosachteiman.co.il/wp-content/uploads/inner/dbsAttachedFiles/pulmusimrada.pdf) by Adam Bin-Nun about an extensive debate in Yemen 100 years ago how to properly pronounce this word.

Comment: According to the theory you’re advancing here, would that mean there is no difference in pronunciation of a chirik whether or not it is written with a yod?

Comment: @JoelK To the extent that such a difference would derive from a pronunciation of the letter yud as a consonant, that's entirely correct. To the extent that the mater lectionis י marks that the preceding chirik dot is a different vowel mark than you may have otherwise expected, there could be a difference, at least as far as this rule is concerned.

Comment: Other places letters without vowels aren't pronounced are the one ש in יששכר and ketiv forms generally speaking.

Comment: another example https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117899/759