# The second yod in Mechiyael

Tags: grammar-dikduk, parashat-bereishit

[Bereishit 4:18](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0104.htm) contains the word:

> וּמְחִיָּיאֵ֗ל

There is no vowel under the second *yod*, so I assume that it is not pronounced at all.

What is its function?

Is it a *mater lectionis*? Is a *yod* ever used as a *mater lectionis* for a *kamatz*?

Or maybe this is an example of *keri uketiv*?

Or something else?

(I'm unsure if the answer to this question would have any practical ramifications in terms of pronunciation, but I would like to understand more what is going on here.)

Comment: check the Radak https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.4.18?lang=bi&with=Radak&lang2=en

Comment: relevant: https://www.sefaria.org/Minchat_Shai_on_Torah%2C_Genesis.30.18.1?lang=he

Comment: "Is a yod ever used as a mater lectionis for a kamatz?" Does ־ָיו count?

Comment: @msh210 good point. Maybe that’s the model

Comment: @rosends Excellent Radak reference which relates also to subject of Peniel and Penuel (the exchange of the letter Yud for Vav) with Yaacov Avinu (Bereshit 32:31-32) as well as Chanoch ben Yered (Bereshit 5:19-22) and his ascending alive from this physical, material world.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for the kamatz to be on the second yod and have the first be part of the chirik? How do the manuscripts have it?

Comment: @DoubleAA The Leningrad Codex has as you suggest (kamatz on the second yod). In the question I linked to mechon mamre which has as described in the question

Answer (score 1):

> וַיִּוָּלֵ֤ד לַֽחֲנוֹךְ֙ אֶת־עִירָ֔ד וְעִירָ֕ד יָלַ֖ד אֶת־מְחֽוּיָאֵ֑ל
> וּמְחִיָּיאֵ֗ל יָלַד֙ אֶת־מְת֣וּשָׁאֵ֔ל וּמְתֽוּשָׁאֵ֖ל יָלַ֥ד
> אֶת־לָֽמֶךְ:
>
> And Irad was born to Enoch, and Irad begot Mehujael, and Mehijael
> begot Methushael, and Methushael begot Lemech.

Rav Hirsch explains that this is because מחויאל (in his youth) became מחייאל as a result of the declining morals of his generation. That is from a passive resistance to Hashem, the generation turned into an active resistance. The *extra* Yud in the name according to Rav Hirsch is to show this change and make the distinction.

> Irad begat Mechujael, מחוי אל in which godlines was extinguished. When
> the generation was young, it was מחויאל, passive, godliness was
> extinguished int, but later when it was older it was מחייאל, active,
> tried to do away with godliness. It was followed by מתושאל (מתו the
> root of מתים), seeking masses of people.

Note that the transliteration would show the two words as *Mechu-yael* turning into *Mechi-yael*. Thus it is not really a double yud but the vowel on the chet is חִירִק while the *second* yud is the consonent.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question

Comment: @DoubleAA Rav Hirsch explains that the double yud is to show the active attempt to extinguish godliness in the world. It is a matter of showing the active rather than the passive tense.

Comment: Does that make it a kri uktiv? I'm confused how that answers the question

Comment: I think you’re reading more into R Hirsch than what he actually says. R Hirsch is addressing the change from מחויאל to מחיאל. He’s not talking about the double yod at all. His comments would remain precisely the same if the latter mention of the name was spelled מחיאל rather than מחייאל.

Comment: @JoelK No Rav Hirsch transliterates this as *Mechi-yael* in order to show the difference from *Mechu-yael*. Thus it requires both yuds. The first yud is part of the vowel on the chet while the second yud is the consonant.

Comment: @sabbahillel No he doesn’t. Read the first part again. It’s מחוי-אל, God is extinguished, versus מחי-אל, actively extinguishing G-d (ח״ו).

Comment: מחו-יאל is both not passive and also meaninglessness in context (‘they extinguished yael’?)

Comment: @sabahillel are your new final paragraph. Did you click on the link to mechon-mamre in the question, or follow links to Radak or Minchat Shai in the comments there? There is clearly a strong tradition that the kamatz is indeed on the first yod.

Comment: @JoelK I think that the Leningrad Codex putting the kamatz under the second yud is mor logical. I also think the example you point to puts the kamatz under both yuds whic follows the chirik that I reference. Also I think that to compare Mechu-yael to Mechi-yael is more of a comparison